# Content-Type for Post with no parameter

Tags: http, http-post

From .NET code I need to do a HTTP POST of some xml to a customer URL. Some customers want me to use a post parameter and some don't. For those who do want a post parameter we are using something along the lines of

```
Data=UrlEncode(Data)
```

with a header type of Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I now have a customer who wants me to just post the XML without a parameter. 
This conflicts with my basic understanding of application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is data will be in the format of Key=Value and url encoded. If I only put the Value part its not a form as it should be and I suspect the customers web server will not parse the pose correctly.

The question is what is the correct standard for the Content-Type header for a post without parameters of an XML? Should it be text/xml or something else? The web server on the other side should still read the post data obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content-type HTTP header field describes the internet media type of the payload. So yes, it it's plain xml, it could be "text/xml" or "application/xml". There's nothing wrong with that, "even" in POST requests.